# Ask question about class diagram of flex

Tags: apache-flex

I want to figure down  the class structure of flex. Where can i get the assumption diagram of Flex framework?

Answer (score 1):

I don't sure if there any Flex 4 class diagram exists but [here](http://flexonblog.files.wordpress.com/2008/02/fx2api_01.pdf) you can find Flex 2 class diagram which is actual for Flex 3 in common. In addition, [here](http://flexonblog.files.wordpress.com/2008/02/as3api_01.pdf) is Flash Player's ActionScript class diagram.